# How to take an element inside an url

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I have an url rewrited like this : http://localhost/test/boutique/index.php/language/fr

I would know if I can take an element inside because `var_dump($_GET['language'])` return nothing.

the original url is http://localhost/test/boutique/index.php?language=fr (original). In this case `$_GET['language']` works fine.

I need the element  : fr when it's rewrited to identified the good language.

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You should get request URI with **`$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`** and parse it.

## Here is simple example which might help you get the idea for achieving your goal:

```
$temp = explode(".php", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

// $temp[1] -> /language/fr
$url = explode("/", substr($temp[1], 1));

// $url[0] -> language , $url[1] -> fr
echo $url[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get it in CodeIgniter???
If it's in CodeIgniter then try to get the value using code.
    $val = $this->segment->uri(3);